# How to group data based from two collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Following are my two collections

```
users:{
  _id: "",
  email: "test@gmail.com",
  department: "hr"
}

details:{
  _id: "", 
 email: "abc@gmail.com"
  some_data:[
    {user_email: "test@gmail.com", ....},
    {user_email: "test1@gmail.com", ....},
    {user_email: "test@gmail.com", ....},
  ]

}
```

What I require is an output saying top 3 departments in the details based on email. 
Example:

```
If I query for email: abc@gmail.com, I must get
[
{department: "hr", count: 4},
{department: "finance", count: 3},
{department: "IT", count: 2}
]
```

I know the db design is horrible but I cannot do anything about it now. So how can this be achieved in MongoDB.

I want the results from `details.some_data` but grouped based on the `department`field of `users`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which collection do you query upon and how did you get the resultant array, with department as `hr` 3 times with `4` count each? Can you edit your question with proper input documents and the correct expected output.

Comment: @BatScream, My Apologies. Ctrl-c, ctrl-v caused the repeated result. Edited the question.

Comment: No issues. Still it would be better if you edit the question to include the actual test data, for both the `collections`, that would give you the output that you have posted. that would make everything clear.