# How to fetch and group data from mongodb collection where each object have same value in a group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, merge, grouping

Already reviewed questions and solutions: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521552/group-collection-data-by-multiple-fields-mongodb) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441301/how-to-group-data-based-from-two-collections-in-mongodb) but not getting clear understanding regarding select data and group them.

MongoDB schema and data I have:

**Currency Model**

```
 [ { currency: 'USD',
     status: 1,
     user_id: '123',
     price: 43.67,
     quantity: 22019 },
  { currency: 'USD',
    status: 1,
    user_id: '234',
    price: 43.69,
    quantity: 22019,
  },
  { currency: 'USD',
    status: 1,
    user_id: '456',
    price: 43.67,
    quantity: 8,
   }... more 100 data ]
```

**What I want as a result:**

> Want to merge Quantity value for 1st and 3rd record **as it has same price**.
>   The same price containing record quantity get merged.

Is it possible to do with query/ filter/ projection? And how can we Effectively get data and merge based on the same price condition i.e. Total quantity is **22019 + 8** having price **43.67**.

Comment: After merging the quantity gets added, price will be same _and_ what happens to the other fields, like `user_id`?

Comment: @prasad_, nothing will happen happen. I just wanted to get quantity total based on different prices.

Comment: This group stage will do that: `{ $group: { _id: "$price",  qty: { $sum: "$quantity" } } }`

Comment: @prasad_ Can I use this with mongoose too?

Comment: The syntax may be different. You have to check with mongoose documentation.

Comment: @prasad_, perfectly...! it worked for me thank you. I have implemented as, OrdersModel.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$price", qty: { $sum: "$quantity" } } } ]).then(data => {}) , will you please answer this question so that I can mark it as solved. It'll be helpful to other nodejs developers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As solution given by @prasad_ in comment section,
 - Got sum of quantity according to price group using aggregation in mongoose:

```
CurrencyModel.aggregate([
         { $group: 
             { _id: "$price", 
               qty: { $sum: "$quantity" } 
             } 
         } 
    ]).then(data => {console.log(data);})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$price",
           quantity: { $sum:  "$quantity" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```